Creating boxplots with individual data points and individual labels
I'm trying to create a simple boxplot with individual data points and individual labels. It's no problem creating a boxplot with the data points, but I can't seem to connect the individual labels to the data points in any way that would be clear and accurate.
I have tried to add the labels to a basic boxplot:
tiff(file="mir.tif", height=800, width=500, units ="px")
boxplot(mirna ~ group, data=mirnas_sub, xlab="Classification", 
        ylab="RPM", main="mirna", boxwex=.7, col="white") #, ylim=c(0, 25000))
stripchart(mirna ~ group, 
           data=mirnas_sub, 
           method="jitter", 
           jitter=0.5, 
           pch=20, 
           col="black", 
           vertical=TRUE, 
           add=TRUE)
with(mirnas_sub, text(group, mirna, labels=dog, pos=4, offset=0.5))
dev.off()

With this, all the labels just run down the middle of the boxplot and aren't really connected to their data point (other than being in the right place on the y axis). I have to scatter the points and the labels quite wide to avoid overlapping, but the labels just stay in the middle of the plot.
I also tried ggplot2.
tiff(file="mir_labels.tif", height=1000, width=600, units="px")
ggplot(mirnas_sub, aes(x=group, y=mirna, color=group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0.2)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=dog), position=position_jitter(width=0.2), vjust=-0.5)
dev.off()

Here, the data points and the labels aren't really connected either and it's hard to see which label should represent which data point. I tried also creating a boxplot with just the labels and with no dots, but even then the labels would overlap and it is just harder to be accurate. When I tried using "check_overlap = TRUE", some overlapping data points were simply removed from the plot instead of scattering the data points wider from each other.
What should I do to create a clear and accurate boxplot with individual data points AND labels?

First make sure that group is a factor. Next, to get the same jitter for points and text, we create group_jit beforehand. Since jitter is stochastic, we use set.seed to make it reproducible.
> mirnas_sub$group <- as.factor(mirnas_sub$group)
> set.seed(42)
> mirnas_sub$group_jit <- jitter(as.numeric(mirnas_sub$group))
> 
> tiff(file="mir.tif", height=800, width=500, units ="px")
> boxplot(mirna ~ group, data=mirnas_sub, xlab="Classification", 
+         ylab="RPM", main="mirna", boxwex=.7, col="white") #, ylim=c(0, 25000))
> with(mirnas_sub, points(group_jit, mirna, pch=20, col=group) )#, ylim=c(0, 25000))
> with(mirnas_sub, text(group_jit, mirna, labels=dog, pos=4, offset=0.5))
> dev.off()


If you want monochrome, just use col='black' as in your original code.

Data:
> set.seed(42)
> mirnas_sub <- data.frame(
+   mirna=rnorm(100, mean=1000, sd=200),
+   group=gl(2, 50, labels=c("Control", "Treatment")),
+   dog=sample(letters, 100, replace=TRUE)
+ )

